# How to configure threshold/distance when swiping on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have swipeable tableview cells. The intention is to let the user swipe rows left or right completely (swipe out completely), and the swiped row gets removed from the table (like how Inbox by Gmail works). Everything works fine, but I had a question.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let swipeRightAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        let item = self.myItems[indexPath.row]
        self.swipeRight(item) //do something
        self.myItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        success(true)
    })

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [swipeRightAction])
 }
```

How can I set the threshold/distance (how much the user has to swipe before the action is taken)? Currently, the user has to swipe half way, before the row gets swiped out. Can I change this point so the user only needs to swipe a little (say 20% of the way) to swipe out the row?

Comment: 1. never knew there was something called `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` :)  2. Have you seen such ever implemented in any apps? 3. Interesting question overall. upvoted

Comment: While this is not a solution to your problem, I urge you to consider this. A 20% swipe to delete "may" cause incorrect deletes to register while the user is scrolling your tableview as opposed to the half-way default swipe which is a much more clear indication that the intent of the user was to delete the cell.

Comment: @Honey: It was introduced in UITableView with iOS 11, so it's quite new. More about this API [here](https://hackernoon.com/uitableview-leading-trailing-swipe-actions-in-ios-11-18cb1f267f8a).

Comment: @Vin Gazoil: that article has nothing to do with this question, as well as most other articles that cover just a basic functionality that everyone already knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct configuration method for it.

**Solution**

But you can build it yourself:

- add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the table
- allow simultaneous recognitions of gestures
- when a swipe ends check for direction and compute percentage out of the translation
- determine the affected table row
- delete it

**Code**

A swipe of the cells to the left by 20%, leading to the deletion of a row, would look like this in the code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        let swipeGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwiped(_:)))
        swipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc private func onSwiped(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            guard translation.x < 0 else { return }
            let width = self.tableView.bounds.width
            let percentage = -translation.x / width
            print("swiped left percentage:\(percentage)")
            if percentage > 0.2 {
                let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) {
                    print("delete row: \(indexPath.row)")
                    self.dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Demo**

[image: swipe 20% to delete row]

Comment: This would get used in conjunction with leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt right?

Comment: this example would be used in conjunction with a trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt since we swipe to the left

but the same mechanism could be used with a swipe to the right (changing the guard to translation.x > 0 and percentage = translation.x / width)